# How do I select a group of nodes at once in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

How do I select a group of nodes at once in QGIS? I want to draw a square and have all of the points in that square be selected; but the 'select feature by polygon' selects my entire polygon, not just the nodes.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are trying to ask here is - 'How to select a group of nodes in a polygon while editing it?'.

If that is the case then you have to use the *Node Tool* -

1. Select the *Node Tool* from your digitizing toolbar while in editing mode.
2. Click on the polygon whose nodes you want to select.
3. Draw a rectangle by holding the left-click of your mouse.

Now all the nodes of that polygon lying within the rectangle drawn will get selected.

The part enclosed in red in the image below is the *Node Tool* - [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Selection button with down arrow to "Select by rectangle".